# how to parallel process in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing

I have 1,000,000 records to process. if you use single code get 160,000 / day.

i want with python code 1,000,000 / day, what is the right function? (thread / multiprocesing / subprocess/ etc)

**my single code :**

```
result = cursor.fetchall()

def myProcces(id,data):
    ......

for row in result:
    myProcces(row[0],row)
```

Comment: Where are you fetching the records from? Where does your output go to? How long does it take to simply fetch the records with no processing at all? How long does it take to just process 1,000 records if you have already prefetched them in advance?

Comment: record fetching from pgsql (database), then the record to process in myproces(). in myproces we call the API and compare the data from API and database. after that, we update/insert depends on the condition. In 3hours we get 20.000 record process

Comment: Thank you for trying, but you kind of missed the point of my question. I am trying to separate the time for getting the data out of the database, from the time to process it, from the time to save results. If you can get all 1 million records in 40 seconds without processing, your task is likely CPU-bound and you probably need multi-processing. If it takes 23 hours to simply get the data from pgsql, then your task is likely IO-bound and you probably need multi-threading.

Comment: So, to clarify. Please can you say the time to purely get and not process 1,000 records. And then the time to process 1,000 starting from when you have fetched all 1,000 in advance. Thank you.

Comment: 2 seconds = to get and not process 1,000 records from DB, and
9 minutes  = to process 1,000 records after get from DB

Comment: Ok, so your times are heavily dependent on the processing time rather than the I/O time, so multi-threading will probably not help you much - assuming the processing doesn't involve any I/O (disk file or network access) - is that correct? So, it looks like your options are to speed up the actual processing by improving your algorithm or code, or to use multi-processing. Next question is whether the processing of one record is dependent on any contents or results of any other record? And finally, please share your code for processing a single record along with representative sample data.

Answer (score 2):

Your choice of module should be based on the type of processing you mean to do using the code. Please elaborate on the type of task at hand a little further.

1. Multithreading: you should use this if the task at hand is I/O bound process like an API call/ request-response , involves some sleep or waiting time.
2. Multiprocessing : you should use this if the task at hand is more CPU intensive i.e. involves lot of calculation or CPU overhead.

Note: If you try to use multithreading for CPU intensive tasks then it will work with same performance as a single program would.

3. Combination of Multithreading and Multiprocessing: If the program involves both wait time and CPU bound part you could use a combination of both.

Comment: Looking at your example, I think you are fetching data from a database (I/O bound process) and myprocess is a calculation(CPU bound process) @Arif hidayah

Comment: yes, in my single program i fetching from db and myproces is call api <= it is my case. and the other case in myproces is compare data from excel and the result is update or insert to db. @Niru